# Shifting draw command relative to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to do a block diagram using nodes in TikZ. I need to draw a speaker to symbolize that a signal is an audio signal.

This is the code for the tikzpicture:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, minimum width=1.2cm, minimum height=0.8cm, align=center]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=0.5}]

\node[block, text width=1.4cm](am_demod) at (0, 0){Envelope detector};

% Rama tono
\node[block, above right=0.4cm and 0.5cm of am_demod](lpf_tono) {$LPF$};
\node[block, text width=1.4cm, right=0.4cm of lpf_tono](cf_tono) {Corrector de fase};

% Rama FM (ref)
\node[block, right=0.5cm of am_demod](bpf_fm) {$BPF$};
\node[block, right=0.4cm of bpf_fm](lim) {Limitador};
\node[block, right=0.4cm of lim](bpf_fm2) {$BPF$};
\node[block, right=0.4cm of bpf_fm2](dt) {$\frac{d}{dt}$};
\node[block, text width=1.4cm, right=0.4cm of dt](env) {Envelope detector};
\node[block, text width=1.4cm, right=0.4cm of env](cf_ref) {Corrector de fase};

% Rama morse
\node[block, below right=0.8cm and 0.5cm of am_demod](bpf_morse) {$BPF$};
\node[draw,circle, minimum size=0.6cm, right=0.7cm of bpf_morse](mul) {};
\node[block, right=0.7cm of mul](lpf_morse) {$LPF$};
\node[below=0.4cm of mul, align=center](cos) {$2 \cdot cos(2\pi f_{morse}t)$};

\draw[scale=0.25, shift=($(mul.north) + (0mm, 0.8mm)$)] (11mm,2mm) -- +(0mm,-4mm)
    (13mm,4mm) -- +(0mm,-8mm)
    (15mm,6mm) -- +(0mm,-12mm)
    (0mm,0mm) -- +(0mm,-3mm) -- +(4mm,-3mm) -- +(9mm,-7mm) -- +(9mm,7mm) -- +(4mm,3mm) -- +(0mm,3mm) -- +(0mm,0mm);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm using the following tikz libraries:

```
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, arrows, angles, quotes, patterns, positioning}
```

My problem is I don't know the correct syntax to use in the last draw command, when I try to shift the drawing by a node.north coordinate plus an offset.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please provide a sketch, what your code should produce.

Comment: try the following: `\draw[scale=0.25, xshift=-40mm] 
    (11mm,2mm) -- +(0mm,-4mm)
    (13mm,4mm) -- +(0mm,-8mm)
    (15mm,6mm) -- +(0mm,-12mm)
    (0mm,0mm)  -- +(0mm,-3mm) -- +(4mm,-3mm) -- +(9mm,-7mm) 
               -- +(9mm, 7mm) -- +(4mm, 3mm) -- +(0mm,3mm) 
               -- +(0mm,0mm);` and for the block "envelope detector add `anchor=west`
`

Answer (score 2):

Shift of some path as you like to do, is not possible. However you can at shift consider coordinate of this node. For example, if node is positioned right from `(0,0)`, that you shift path which draw your loudspeaker for example by `\draw[scale=0.25, xshift=-40mm] ...`

Your image can be drawn on more consistent and concise way. By use of the `chain` library the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 5mm,
      start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {scale=0.5}, 
     block/.style = {draw, minimum width=13mm, minimum height=11mm, 
                     align=center},
         C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size =9mm}
                     ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain}]
\node[anchor=west] (am_demod)   {Envelope\\ detector}; % <---
\node (bpf_fm2)                 {$BPF$};
\node (lim)                     {Limitador};
\node (bpf_fm)                  {$BPF$};
\node (dt)                      {$\frac{d}{dt}$};
\node (env)                     {Envelope\\ detector};
\node (cf_ref)                  {Corrector\\ de fase};
    \end{scope}
% Rama tono
\node[block, above=of bpf_fm2]  (lpf_tono) {$LPF$};
\node[block, above=of lim]      (cf_tono)   {Corrector\\  de fase};
% Rama morse
\node[block, below=of bpf_fm2]  (bpf_morse) {$BPF$};
\node[C, below=of lim]  (mul)   {};
\node[block, below=of bpf_fm] (lpf_morse) {$LPF$};
\node[below=of mul]     (cos)   {$2 {\cdot} cos(2\pi f_{\mathrm{morse}}t)$};

\draw[scale=0.25, xshift=-40mm] % <---
    (11mm,2mm) -- +(0mm,-4mm)
    (13mm,4mm) -- +(0mm,-8mm)
    (15mm,6mm) -- +(0mm,-12mm)
    (0mm,0mm)  -- +(0mm,-3mm) -- +(4mm,-3mm) -- +(9mm,-7mm) 
               -- +(9mm, 7mm) -- +(4mm, 3mm) -- +(0mm,3mm) 
               -- +(0mm,0mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As I see your block scheme, it is not complete. Missed are arrows, which connect  their blocks. How this is done and if they have labels, is not known. I only can recommend to use `quotes` library for arrows' labels.

[image]

**Edit:** You may draw your loudspeaker as `pic` image and positioned it as input to main branch of nodes.

Also let anticipate, that main branch of nodes are connected by arrows without labels. Then the MWE, which consider those arrows drawn by macro `join` (defined in the `chains`)  and use `\pic` for loudspeaker, is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 5mm,
      start chain = A going right,
every node/.style = {scale=0.5},
       arr/.style = {draw=gray, semithick, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
     block/.style = {draw, minimum width=13mm, minimum height=11mm,
                     align=center},
         C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=9mm},
pics/speaker/.style = {code={%
  \draw (0,0) coordinate[right=0.45] (-LS)
        -- +(0,-0.15)   -- +(0.2,-0.15) -- +(0.45,-0.35)
        -- +(0.45,0.35) -- +(0.2, 0.15) -- +(0,0.15)
        -- cycle
    (0.6,0.1) to[bend left] +(0,-0.2)
    (0.7,0.2) to[bend left] +(0,-0.4)
    (0.8,0.3) to[bend left] +(0,-0.6);
    }}
                       ]
% loudspeaker
\pic (in) {speaker};
%%%% positioning of blocks      
    \begin{scope}[nodes={block, on chain, join=by arr}]
\node[right=2mm of in-LS]  {Envelope\\ detector};  % A-1
\node   {$BPF$};                            % A-2
\node   {Limitador};
\node   {$BPF$};
\node   {$\frac{d}{dt}$};
\node   {Envelope\\ detector};
\node   {Corrector\\ de fase};              % A-7
    \end{scope}
% Rama tono
\node[block, above=of A-2]  (A-2a)  {$LPF$};
\node[block, above=of A-3]  (A-3a)  {Corrector\\ de fase};
% Rama morse
\node[block, below=of A-2]  (A-2b) {$BPF$};
\node[C,     at={(A-3 |- A-2b)}]    (A-3b)  {};
\node[block, below=of A-4]  (A-4b)  {$LPF$};
\node[below=of A-3b]        (cos)   {$2\cdot\cos(2\pi f_{\mathrm{morse}}t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]